# How can I solve the output error in flipping a coin?

Tags: python, function, coin-flipping

I am writing code about the probability of flipping a coin as follows, but I keep getting errors.

```
import random

tries = 0
number = random.randint(0, 1)
def coin_probability(hehe):
    for a in range(1, 101):
        heads = 0; tails = 0
        tries += 1
        if tries <= 10:
            if number == 0:
                heads += 1
            cp = heads/n
            print("%4d 번째까지 던지기에서 앞면이 나온 확률 :%5d%%" %(tries, cp))
        else:
            if number == 0:
                heads += 1
            cp = heads/n
            print("%4d 번째까지 던지기에서 앞면이 나온 확률 :%5d%%" %(tries, cp))
n = int(input("동전 던지기 시도 횟수를 입력(1 - 100) : "))
print('*' * 47)
print('총 %d번 동전 던지기에서 앞면이 나올 확률 :  %s' %(n, coin_probability(n))) `
```

I want the probability to come out one by one from 1 to 10, and display 10 units from 11 to 100. For example:

```
1 번째까지~: (probability)% 
2 번째까지~: (probability)%
3 번째까지~: (probability)%
...
10 번째까지~: (probability)%
20 번째까지~: (probability)%
...
```

it should be printed like this.
(※I set heads to 0 and tails to 1.)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's what you want:

```py
import random

def coin_probability(attempts):
    heads = 0
    for try_number in range(1, attempts + 1):
        number = random.randint(0, 1)

        if number == 0: 
            heads += 1

        cp = (heads/try_number) * 100

        if try_number <= 10 or (try_number % 10) == 0:
            print(f"{try_number} 번째까지 던지기에서 앞면이 나온 확률: {round(cp,5)}")


def main():
    attempts = int(input("동전 던지기 시도 횟수를 입력: "))
    print('*' * 47)
    coin_probability(attempts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
import random

def coin_probability(n):
    tries = 0
    heads = 0
    for a in range(n):
        number = random.randint(0, 1)
        tries += 1
        if tries <= 10:
            if number == 0:
                heads += 1
            cp = 100*heads/tries
            print("%4d 번째까지 던지기에서 앞면이 나온 확률 :%5f%%" %(tries, cp))
        else:
            if number == 0:
                heads += 1
            cp = 100*heads/tries
            if tries%10 == 0:
               print("%4d 번째까지 던지기에서 앞면이 나온 확률 :%5f%%" %(tries, cp))
    return cp
n = int(input("동전 던지기 시도 횟수를 입력(1 - 100) : "))
print('*' * 47)
p = coin_probability(n)
print('*' * 47)
print('총 %d번 동전 던지기에서 앞면이 나올 확률 :  %s' %(n, p))
```

Comment: That's the answer I want !!  But I'll just ask one more question.  If I want to place this part '*********' before '총 %d번 동전 던지기에서 앞면이 나올 확률 :  %s', what should I do??

Comment: @Pia I have updated the answer to print "*********" before the final line.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the print() after another if with

```
...
else:
    if tries % 10 == 0:
        print("something", cp, tries)
```

also you give n to your function as "hehe" but never use it? Other than that you could be a little more specific what kind of error occurs.